# How to apply calculations in a Dataframe per group based on column values?

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe showing 3 different futures prices per Trade Date, which are numbered in column "number". 
[image]

Now I'm struggling to calculate the following:

Per unique trade date, I want to divide the value in the Close column where "number" = 2 with the value in the Close column where "number" = 1. 
How do I do this?
Many thanks!

Comment: Better is text format of data, for possible copy them.

Comment: Don't post data or code as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby('Datetime')
        .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['number'].eq(2), 'Close'] / 
                         x.loc[x['number'].eq(1), 'Close']))
print (df1)
Datetime              
2013-01-02  2013-01-02    1.071795
2013-01-03  2013-01-03    1.064151
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

Another idea with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot('Datetime','number','Close')
df1['new'] = df1[2] / df1[1]

print (df)
number         1      2      3       new
Datetime                                
2013-01-02  15.6  16.72  18.06  1.071795
2013-01-03  15.9  16.92    NaN  1.064151
```